# Using Excel VBA to get stock quotes from Google or Bloomberg thinks I'm a bot

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel macro that will get a stock quote from either Google or Bloomberg. Each site seems to detect that I'm not calling from a web browser, and refuses to work.

Here is a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the problem. If you copy and paste the URL value directly into a web browser, it works fine. But if you look at the result returned by my code, it's a message that essentially says, "We think you're not human." Any way around this?

(The Bloomberg version is actually preferable because it returns JSON. The Google version returns HTML that I would have to parse. But at this point I'll take anything.)

```
Private Sub TestQuote()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim http As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    'BLOOMBERG QUERY
    sURL = "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/MSFT%3AUS?timeFrame=1_DAY"

    'GOOGLE QUERY
    'sURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=MSFT"

    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    http.Open "GET", sURL, False
    http.send

    Debug.Print http.responseText
End Sub
```

Comment: You are asking how to violate the terms of the website?

Comment: For Google, perhaps for the letter of the law... maybe. But the Bloomberg version is an API... one would think they would expect it to be an automated function? Their response seems to suggest that I need to have cookies enabled. At the end of the day, I'm just a guy trying to update my stock portfolio and I'd rather not have to lookup 20 values a day.

Comment: If you're on Excel 2019+, there's a built-in stocks menu on the data tab.

Is there some missing functionality you're looking for, or are you on an older version?

Comment: Try [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co). They have a free api that you could possibly use for this purpose.

Comment: I was using AlphaVantage at one point. But the free version will only let you look up 5 stocks per minute. Too painful when you want have a list of 20 quotes to check. The lowest paid version is $30/month which is even more ridiculous. So then I thought, "Hey, I can do Google searches for free." Apparently not from Excel.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping You're a genius! I had no idea this feature existed. I've been writing VBA code to do this from various sources for 10 years. I can't tell you the frustration this will save me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@OwlsSleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7354796/owlssleeping) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913751/using-excel-vba-to-get-stock-quotes-from-google-or-bloomberg-thinks-im-a-bot/59924504#comment105952764_59913751), the current version of Excel has this feature (ability to lookup stock information) built in.

From the documentation page [**Get a stock quote**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54):

> **Get a stock quote**
>
> *Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web*
>
> To insert a stock price into Excel, first convert text into the Stocks data type. Then you can use another column to extract certain details relative to that data type, like the stock price, change in price, and so on.
>
> > Note: The Stocks data type is only available to Microsoft 365 accounts or those with a free Microsoft Account. You must also have the English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, or Portuguese editing language added to Office Language Preferences.
>
> 1. Type some text in cells. For example, type a ticker symbol, company name, or fund name into each cell.
> 2. Then select the cells.
> 3. Although it's not required, we recommend creating an Excel table. Later on, this will make extracting online information easier. To create a table, go to Insert > Table.
> 4. With the cells still selected, go to the Data tab, and then click Stocks.
> 5. If Excel finds a match between the text in the cells, and our online sources, it will convert your text to the Stocks data type. You'll know they're converted if they have [an] icon for stocks...
> 6. Select one or more cells with the data type, and the Add Column button will appear. Click that button, and then click a field name to extract more information. For example, for stocks you might pick Price.
>
> ... (further details available in the online docs)

Comment: The comment says, *If you're on Excel 2019+, there's a built-in stocks menu on the data tab.* - but it seems like stock quotes are only in the subscription services *Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web*.  See [Get a stock quote](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54) and [Data Type Stocks not working in Excel 2019](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/data-type-stocks-not-working-in-excel-2019/td-p/1175829).